# Production setting for Keycloak 18 from Bitnami helm chart on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to run Keycloak 18.0.1 as a StatefulSet with the bitnami Helm chart on my Azure AKS Kubernetes cluster. Traefik 2.7 is the Ingress Controller and an external Postgres Database is used. Keycloak is in "proxy"-mode "edge" and doesn't need to handle SSL, because it's handled by traefik, cert-manager & Let's encrypt.

I'm trying to switch it to production mode:

```
2022-07-29 22:43:21,460 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, jdbc-h2, jdbc-mariadb, jdbc-mssql, jdbc-mysql, jdbc-oracle, jdbc-postgresql, keycloak, narayana-jta, reactive-routes, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-health, smallrye-metrics, vault, vertx]
2022-07-29 22:43:21,466 WARN  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.KeycloakMain] (main) Running the server in development mode. DO NOT use this configuration in production.
```

Therefore I tried using the following values during helm chart installation:

```
cache:
  enabled: true

auth:
  adminUser: ****
  adminPassword: ****
  managementUser: ****
  managementPassword: ****

proxy: edge

postgresql:
  enabled: false

externalDatabase:
  host: ****
  port: 5432
  user: ****
  password: ****
  database: keycloak

resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 0.5
    memory: 512Mi
  limits:
    cpu: 1
    memory: 1Gi

extraEnvVars:
  - name: KEYCLOAK_PRODUCTION
    value: "true"
  - name: KC_HOSTNAME
    value: "<external host name>"
  - name: KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS
    value: "false"
```

As soon as I add the env vars for production, I'm getting the following error:

```
at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getXAConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:352)
 at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:216)
 at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:513)
 at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:494)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
 at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1126)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-07-29 18:27:20,885 WARN  [io.agroal.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://***********:5432/keycloak?currentSchema=public
```

It seems that the chart wants to go back to the integrated H2 database?

The second problem is the Infinispan cache:

`[org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled`

How can I enable this cache to make the chart work with multiple replicas?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Pascal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to enable production mode:

```
  - name: KEYCLOAK_EXTRA_ARGS
    value: "--auto-build"
```

The error:

```
[org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
```

however still remains.

Comment: I'm surprised that you found `--auto-build` to be the solution when [the Keycloak documentation](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-community/blob/main/design/keycloak.x/configuration.md) states:

"The --auto-build option is not recommended for production deployments due to the additional overhead to the server startup time"

Comment: @jmjohnson85 I suppose there must be some other way to enable production settings. But no luck so far in finding it. Luckily for me, startup time is no issue for our environment as Keycloak is running in HA K8s Cluster.

Comment: I'm also using the Bitnami Helm chart and I'm not having any performance or startup issues but even with `--auto-build` I still receive the `Running the server in development mode` warning...